# Swift iOS : Serial Function Execution

Tags: swift, function

I wish to create a function that runs 3 internal functions 1 after the 1 and repeat that process 3 times. The problem I am finding is that all 3 functions execute simultaneously.

Currently when I test the app it turns green and that is it. Where I would like it to turn red for 30 seconds, then green for 10, then repeat that process 3 times.

I would like to keep the process open so I may add conditions such as "Play a sound at 4 seconds in) and allow the overall times to changeable in the future.

CODE:

```
import UIKit


var timer = Timer()
var intCount = 0
var seconds = 0

let greenColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let redColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

// Start Button
@IBAction func Start(_ sender: Any)
{
    repeat
    {
        performTimer()
        intCount += 1
    }while intCount < 2

    StartHide.isHidden = true
}

func performTimer()
{
    timer1() // Execute -> Finish
    timer2() // Execute -> Finish
}

func timer1()
{

    // Set Seconds
    seconds = 30
    // Colour for 30 Seconds 
    view.backgroundColor = redColor
    // Run Timer
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerPage.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func timer2()
{
    // Set Seconds
    seconds = 10
    // Colour for 10 Seconds 
    view.backgroundColor = greenColor
    // Run Timer
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerPage.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func counter()
{

    seconds -= 1

    if (seconds == 0)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Surely there is a simple way to stop functions running simultaneously?

Comment: Post real actual code, not pseudo code. Clearly explain the desired/expected result and the actual result.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly

Comment: None of your functions are running simultaneously. Please clarify what is happening exactly and clarify what you want to happen.

Comment: @rmaddy I will also edit this into the post. Currently when I test the app it turns green and that is it. Where I would like it to turn red for 30 seconds, then green for 10, then repeat that process 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timers are running simultaneously (a better word is asynchronously) because of this:

```
repeat
{
    performTimer()
    intCount += 1
}while intCount < 2
```

and this:

```
func performTimer()
{
    timer1() // Execute -> Finish
    timer2() // Execute -> Finish
}
```

The call to `timer1` will return as soon as the timer has been created, *not when the timer counts down to 30 seconds*. Same goes for `timer2` and `performTimer` methods.

So you are creating all these timers in a very short time and they all share a `seconds` variable. That's bad.

To fix this, you should only create new times after the one running has finished.

```
let count = 0
let seconds = 0
var currTimer: Timer!
func start() {
    timer30s()
}

func timer30s() {
    seconds = 30
    currTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: selector(handleTimer30s), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func timer10s() {
    seconds = 10
    currTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: selector(handleTimer10s), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func handleTimer30s() {
    if seconds > 0 {
        seconds -= 1
        return
    }
    currTimer.invalidate()
    timer10s()
    view.backgroundColor = redColor
}

func handleTimer10s() {
    if seconds > 0 {
        seconds -= 1
        return
    }
    count += 1
    currTimer.invalidate()
    if count < 3 {
        timer30s()
    }
    view.backgroundColor = greenColor
}
```

Comment: I used a repeat to allow more functionality in the counter process. Say I wish to play a sound or change the colour on a certain time within that count, or update a label; how would one do that now?

Comment: Oh so you want to play a sound or change the color in the middle of the 30 seconds? I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry I should add that in my question post (Updating now)

Comment: @DarrylMitchell Edited.